# Python Convert String to Byte

Tags: python, serial-port, type-conversion, byte, pyserial

I am trying to do some serial input and output operations, and one of those is to send an 8x8 array to an external device (Arduino). The [pySerial](http://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/) library requires that the information that I send be a byte. However, in my python code, the 8x8 matrix is made up of types `<class 'str'>`. Here's my sending function:

```
import serial
import Matrix

width = 8
height = 8
portName = 'COM3'

def sendMatrix(matrix):
    try:
        port = serial.Serial(portName, 9600, timeout = 1000000)
        port.setDTR(0)
        print("Opened port: \"%s\"." % (portName))
        receivedByte = port.read()
        print(int(receivedByte))
        if (receivedByte == '1'):
            port.write('1')
        bytesWritten = 0
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                value = matrix.getPoint(col, row)
                bytesWritten += port.write(value)//ERROR HERE!
        print(int(port.read()));
        port.close()
        print("Data (%d) sent to port: \"%s\"." % (bytesWritten, portName))
    except:
        print("Unable to open the port \"%s\"." % (portName))


def main():
    matrix = Matrix.Matrix.readFromFile('framefile', 8, 8)
    matrix.print()
    print(type(matrix.getPoint(0, 0)))
    print(matrix.getPoint(1, 1))
    sendMatrix(matrix)

main()
```

Now, I have a class `Matrix`, which contains a field `map`, which is the array in question, and I will include that code here too, but the problem I'm having is that each element in the array is of type `str`, but I need to convert it to a byte. I can disregard possible loss of data, since in practice, I only use 0's and 1's.

My Matrix Class:

```
class Matrix(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.map = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

    def setPoint(self, x, y, value):
        if ((x >= 0) and (x < self.width) and (y >= 0) and (y < self.height)):
            self.map[y][x] = value

    def getPoint(self, x, y):
        if ((x >= 0) and (x < self.width) and (y >= 0) and (y < self.height)):
            return self.map[y][x]

    def print(self):
        for row in range(self.height):
            for col in range(self.width):
                print(str(self.map[row][col])+" ", end="")
            print()

    def save(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        for row in range(self.height):
            for col in range(self.width):
                f.write(str(self.map[row][col]))
            f.write('\n')
        f.close()

    def toByteArray(self):
        matrixBytes = bytearray(self.width * self.height)
        for row in range(self.height):
            for col in range(self.width):
                matrixBytes.append(int(self.map[row][col]))
        return matrixBytes

    def getMap(self):
        return self.map

    def readFromFile(filename, width, height):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        lines = list(f)
        matrix = Matrix(width, height)
        f.close()
        for row in range(len(lines)):
            matrix.map[row] = lines[row].strip('\n')
        return matrix
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `bytes(matrix.toByteArray())` ?

Comment: matrix is an object, and it contains a width, height, and a 2 dimensional array inside of that. It's not simply an iterable structure.

Comment: Sure, but the code for your `matrix.toByteArray` method looks like it serializes the matrix data correctly into a bytearray, and the built-in `bytes` function will produce a bytes object from that bytearray.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To transform a unicode string to a byte string in Python do this:

```
>>> 'foo'.encode('utf_8')
b'foo'
```

To transform a byte string to a unicode string:

```
>>> b'foo'.decode('utf_8')
'foo'
```

See [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) in the Standard library.

The available encodings are documented [in this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). Commonly used ones are `utf_8`, `utf_8_sig`, `ascii`, `latin_1` and `cp1252`. See [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) at Wikipedia.

Helpful for debbugging can be `raw_unicode_escape`. See [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings).

Answer (score 6):

in Python 3.x, You can use `bytes` and `str` like below.

```
>>> bytes('foo'.encode())
b'foo'

>>> a = bytes('foo'.encode())
>>> str(a.decode())
'foo'
```