# How does one add string prefixes to variables in python?

Tags: python, string, encoding, literals, prefix

The term 'string prefix' is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringprefix).

What if you have a string that has been assigned to a variable already, how do you add the string prefix to that (without using the same string)? This can be assigned a new variable, or reassigned to the same one.

Comment: "String Encoding declarations" is not an actual term, and it would be a terrible term if it was, as it has nothing to do with encoding. Some rando just edited their own made-up terminology into that answer.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica Then what is it called?

Comment: I don't think there's a name.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica people make up new terms all the time, the way language works is if you understand what they are saying. Do you understand what they are talking about?

Comment: If it didn't literally appear in the sentence "'Letters before strings here are called "String Encoding declarations".", I would not know what they were talking about. I would have guessed it was a misleading term for a [PEP 263 encoding comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), which is a completely different thing. There is only one google hit for `python "string encoding declaration"` using the "term" in this way, and it's by the guy who made the edit.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I would think it's something that needs a name, does 'prefix' or 'string prefix' work at least?

Comment: You can't ping arbitrary users like that on Stack Overflow. jdi didn't receive your attempted ping. jdi wasn't the person who inserted that term into the answer anyway - [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11279428/revisions) shows it was [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445131/eric-leschinski), and judging by their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937172/what-does-u-before-a-string-in-python-mean), they misread the docs for encoding comments.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I don't have the rep to comment there. Didn't jdi accept the edit though? So prefix then? Since that term was used before?

Comment: jdi has been barely active for years, and had no activity for a window of time over a month long surrounding the edit. They were probably not paying attention.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica ok thanks for looking into that. I changed the wording, but can be changed again if still confusing.

Comment: I think this is a debate about the terminology. I would suggest it right now.

Comment: @Stathis Alexopoulos I'm not debating, I'll accept whatever it is, if it has to be written out in explanation each time, ok, but i think terms are preferable.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python 3? [The `u` prefix only exists to accommodate legacy code now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464968/4518341), and it doesn't actually do anything. Are you asking about different prefixes? They all work differently. See [Transform string to f-string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44757222/4518341), [Convert regular Python string to raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4415259/4518341), [Convert String to Byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40235958/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea so for the answer one would have to make a function for all the cases, depending on the letter selected, that's what it sounds like.

Comment: @dsfgh A function? I guess you could write one, but I wouldn't. The different prefixes are fundamentally different things. For example f-strings don't correspond 1-to-1 with `str.format` since they can contain expressions, and [those expressions are not restricted, so naively evaluating them would be a security risk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47599254/4518341). I'll see if I can write you an answer to explain the others.

Comment: @wjandrea cool maybe I'll make the function myself, any useful info helps.

Comment: @dsfgh Not to burst your bubble, but the only reason to write that function would be as a learning exercise. If you *need* a function that does that, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: BTW forgot to mention, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice. Also, one of your edits chopped a sentence in half: "According to how the term is used here," ...

Answer (score 2):

You can't retroactively add or remove a string literal prefix. Once its been made, it's just a `str` (or `bytes` with a `b` prefix). If you need to convert something that was a `bytes` literal to `str` or vice-versa, you use the `bytes.decode` or `str.encode` method respectively, like you would on any `bytes` or `str`, regardless of whether it began as a literal or not, because there is no difference between literal and non-literal strings immediately after the literal is evaluated.

Comment: Pedantic note I didn't want in the answer itself: Technically, `str` literals might be interned where non-literal `str`s rarely are, but this is not relevant to use unless you're incorrectly using `is` for string comparisons.

Comment: So if you have sg = 'stng' how can you get sgl = u'stng' from sg (without using 'stng')

Comment: @dsfgh: If you're on Python 3, they're both the same string. `u` is an optional, meaningless prefix on Python 3 for aid in porting Python 2 scripts. It just says "this string can contain Unicode", but on Python 3, that's how all `str` are already.

Comment: Ok an example with another string prefix then.

Comment: @dsfgh: Did you see my first sentence? It *cannot* be done in the general case. You can change *certain* `str` to look like `bytes` literals (`'stng'.encode('latin-1')`) but that assumes they contain only latin-1 characters; if they contain non-latin-1 characters, there is no single equivalent byte. Literals are *literals*; the literal itself possesses or lacks a prefix, you can't retroactively change it.

Comment: if errors occur there could be a notification that it cannot be done. I think the answer would be a function where the prefix can be selected.

Comment: But yeah saying there is no general way is a useful answer to point out also.

Comment: @dsfgh: Trying to write such a prefix selecting function is difficult to the point where, given the limited utility of such a function and the inability to cover all cases, the "benefits" are not worth the trouble of writing. The whole idea is nonsensical to start with, since, as I said, the prefixes only have meaning in terms of literals; stuff like `r` and `f` prefixes are literally impossible to graft on after the fact with anything but the loosest heuristics, and `b` is almost as bad.

Comment: @dsfgh: You're trying to unscramble a scrambled egg and boil it instead.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica that makes it sound like it's hard to do

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't. String prefixes are part of syntax, not data. In other words, they don't create a different *type* of string, but create a string *in a different way*.

- `u` does nothing in Python 3. [It only exists for compatibility with Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464968/4518341).
- `f` [can be emulated with `str.format()` for simple cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44757255/4518341), but to fully emulate an f-string, you'd have to evaluate it, but [that's a security risk since f-strings can contain arbitrary code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47599254/4518341).
- `r` [can be emulated with `str.encode('unicode_escape').decode()` in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13967409/4518341), but not all, for example, this string literal is lossy:

  ```
  >>> r'\x61'
  '\\x61'
  >>> s = '\x61'
  >>> s
  'a'
  >>> s.encode('unicode_escape').decode()
  'a'
  ```
- `b` is an exception in that it actually does create a different type: a `bytes` object. It can be emulated with the [raw_unicode_escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) encoding, though I don't have any experience using it so I'm not sure if it's the same:

  ```
  >>> b'a\x89\u2013'
  b'a\x89\\u2013'
  >>> 'a\x89\u2013'
  'a\x89–'
  >>> 'a\x89\u2013'.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
  b'a\x89\\u2013'
  >>> 'a\x89\u2013'.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('raw_unicode_escape')
  'a\x89–'
  ```

Also just for reference, the grammar calls them [`stringprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringprefix), and just "prefix" in the text.

Answer (score 0):

According to Python **2** [manual](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

> **Unicode Literals in Python Source Code**
>
> In Python source code, Unicode literals are written as strings
> prefixed with the ‘u’ or ‘U’ character: u'abcdefghijk'. Specific code
> points can be written using the \u escape sequence, which is followed
> by four hex digits giving the code point. The \U escape sequence is
> similar, but expects 8 hex digits, not 4.

But in Python 3

> **[The String Type](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)**
>
> Since Python 3.0, the language’s str type contains Unicode characters,
> meaning any string created using "unicode rocks!", 'unicode rocks!',
> or the triple-quoted string syntax is stored as Unicode.
>
> The default encoding for Python source code is UTF-8, so you can
> simply include a Unicode character in a string literal:

As far as it concerns the already created variables, either by user input or by reading a file or whatever, you have to read on each method how to manipulate unicodes